# How to unset MONGO_URL in windows

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How to unset the MONGO_URL of my meteor app in windows. My meteor app is crashing after I ran this code : `set MONGO_URL=mongodb://192.168.1.172:3001/meteor meteor` in cmd. How to unset it and connect it back to the built in db?

`unset MONGO_URL` just not working in windows cmd.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/279072/how-do-i-clear-all-environment-variables-from-a-windows-shell-session

Comment: And [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222724/command-line-to-remove-an-environment-variable-from-the-os-level-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

In windows, it seems like restarting the command prompt will reset the mongo_url that I set. now works fine.