# How do you delete/unset the GIT_EDITOR variable

Tags: git

How do I delete the `GIT_EDITOR` variable?

I set it by error and would like to remove it.

It looks like `git var` can only list variables...

Comment: did you update/add it to .gitconfig file?

Comment: @dkb: a setting in `.gitconfig` is not an environment variable. Note that while you can set `core.editor` in `.gitconfig`, the environment variable overrides this setting (which makes sense on Unix shells where you can run `GIT_EDITOR=experiment git commit`, for instance, to experiment for one command only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are set/exported, and hence unset/unexported, by the outer level *shell* that runs each command.  Hence the way to *un*-set `GIT_EDITOR` completely depends on your shell.

In most Unix-style shells, `unset` is the verb to un-set a variable.  If the variable is marked exported, this not only unsets it in the shell but also removes it from the exported environment.  Unix csh / tcsh uses `unsetenv` instead (its `unset` unsets only *shell* variables, not environment variables; `set` sets shell variables and `setenv` sets environment variables).

I have no idea what do to in DOS-style shells, but [Command line to remove an environment variable from the OS level configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13222724/1256452) has some advice, plus links to additional StackOverflow questions and answers.

Comment: Thank you @torek !
I work in Windows 10 OS and use Git Bash. I was able to unset the GIT_EDITOR by typing in console:
`unset GIT_EDITOR`