# Delete Environment Variable Using Command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there a batch file by which i can delete Environment Variable using cmd??

```
setx TEST "C:\"
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** delete an environment variable using `setx`, however, you can set it to NULL:

`setx TEST ""`

However, the variable is still there.

You can delete it using `REG`

`REG DELETE "HKCU\Environment" /v TEST`

However, using this approach, changes will not take place immediately.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222724/command-line-to-remove-an-environment-variable-from-the-os-level-configuration