# fatal: cannot run C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: github, ssh, digital-ocean

> fatal: cannot run C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe: No such file or
> directory fatal: unable to fork

I am trying to pull a repository from `github`. but I am unable to pull to digitalocean using ssh

Comment: Can you add more information?
What is the platform on which you are trying to execute this?
What do you want to achieve?
Maybe a screenshot could also provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Considering:

- you are using  digitalocean with ssh
- this is a Windows PATH

I assume the issue is between your Windows PC and DigitialOcean, not between DigitalOcean and GitHub.

Regarding the "unable to fork" issue, type in a CMD

```
set GIT_SSH
```

If GIT_SSH is set, try and unset it, or [remove it completely from your environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816308/6309).
Then in that same CMD, try again your SSH to DigitalOcean.