# Batch script to trigger proxy environment

Tags: batch-file

I am having this simple two line script to set and remove my HTTP_PROXY when needed .

```
IF not defined HTTP_PROXY (setx HTTP_PROXY http://user:pass@212.212.212.212:29842) ELSE (REG delete HKCU\Environment /F /V HTTP_PROXY)
IF not defined HTTPS_PROXY (setx HTTPS_PROXY http://user:pass@212.212.212.212:29842) ELSE (REG delete HKCU\Environment /F /V HTTPS_PROXY)
```

what am trying to do is to trigger the HTTP_PROXY environment .

But when i run as administrator the first time , the value is added and proxy is configured .

Second time , The value is removed and the proxy still configured .

Even when i cant even see the **HTTP_PROXY** with environment variable i can still get the config with new terminal with **`echo %HTTP_PROXY%`**

Am i deleting the value wrong , or my problem is with adding ?

Comment: When you use `SetX` the defined variable is not available in the current environment, only in subsequent ones.

Comment: to set the environment for both permanent and current session you can do `(setx HTTP_PROXY http://user:pass@212.212.212.212:29842 & set=HTTP_PROXY http://user:pass@212.212.212.212:29842)..`

Comment: Thanks , i know that the setx work like you said , but am trying to remove this and nether ```setx HTTP_PROXY "" ``` or ```setx HTTP_PROXY``` worked for me , my problem is that i need to remove the setx , and  ``` REG delete HKCU\Environment /F /V HTTP_PROXY ```  deleting the value from system environment but keep it in cmd somehow .

Comment: So you are saying that the HTTP_PROXY is still active after the delete?

Comment: exactly which make no sense at all , even when trying with new command line and do ```curl ifconfig.me``` i still get the old HTTP_PROXY configured , when it has no visible value at Environment Variables on windows .

Comment: Why don't you delete the variables the same way you create them, namely using [`setx`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)? (use `""` to define an empty variable)

Comment: you simply need to then do `setx HTTP_PROXY ""` to set a nul value, then delete the reg entry, also as mentioned by aschipfl now.

Comment: @aschipfl , actually it worked , but needed few mins , when i tried this i had the impression that it should either work immediately or dont work considering the variable is equal to "" then the proxy will be used and set to "" , Thanks for the answer and please consider answering my question so i mark as accepted .

Comment: i ve tried ealier but for some reason its not immediate effect so i assumed it not working , thanks for the help @Gerhard .

Comment: no, it will not be immediate as you need to re-initiate the environment (closing and opening `cmd`). So again back to my first comment, to make it immediate do `setx HTTP_PROXY "" & set HTTP_PROXY=`

Comment: i have no idea if this is a bug with windows 11 or something , but i meant as immediate like opening new command line and trying again , it will need like couple of minutes regrading the new command line , so i will open 5 new CMD and still get the value while there is nothing in the environment variable . its really weird .

Comment: That does not seem possible, but then I do not have Windows 11 so I cannot confirm that.

Comment: yeah its actually really weird , that why i even posted this , the script should be working fine but its acting with this behavior . Thanks a lot for the help .

Comment: Can you confirm that there is not such a value in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` ?

Comment: I have double check now , there is no system variable , nor with reg edit @```HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment```, but still on new CMD , ```echo %HTTP_PROXY``` will return the proxy .

Comment: ok. So I actually went through the upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11, just for this. I am sorry to say that I am not experiencing this issue at all. if I `setx HTTP_PROXY ""` it will be empty when I close `cmd` and open it again. I think you should perhaps edit your quesiton and give some more detail including updated code and perhaps some screenshots of proof how it is still active after `setx`

Comment: Oh thank a lot , I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222724/command-line-to-remove-an-environment-variable-from-the-os-level-configuration/48816308#48816308) apparently the explorer.exe is causing the issue . Thanks a lot for the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222724/command-line-to-remove-an-environment-variable-from-the-os-level-configuration/48816308#48816308) .

its related to Applying Values Without Rebooting , the value will be updated but not instantly , it will take some time so the explorer.exe refresh the values .