Python with venv - Packages downloaded with pip not showing up in "list" (downloaded in the system path...)
I've read several topics and docs on this subject and could not find an "easy" solution for me as I am quite a beginner with Python.
I created a Python virtual environment through venv (on Windows), because I was facing some problems with "PATH" and pip packages.
My venv is created, activated and configured like this :
(fortiupdate.venv) c:\[...]\fortiupdate.venv\Scripts>echo %PATH%
c:\[...]\fortiupdate.venv\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware vSphere CLI\Perl\site\bin;

(fortiupdate.venv) c:\[...]\fortiupdate.venv\Scripts>where python
c:\[...]\fortiupdate.venv\Scripts\python.exe

(fortiupdate.venv) c:\[...]\fortiupdate.venv\Scripts>where pip
c:\[...]\fortiupdate.venv\Scripts\pip.exe

When I install a package with :
pip install django

Download and installation are ok, but "pip list" doesn't return the package django to be installed/available.
I tried :
(fortiupdate.venv) c:\[...]\fortiupdate.venv\Scripts>pip config list

:env:.target='C:\\Users\\[..]\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Scripts'
global.index-url='https://<private_repo>/artifactory/api/pypi/pythonproxy/simple'

I confirm that packages are installed in the ":env:.target" directory, instead of the ".venv/lib/site-packages" directory
It doesn't really matter to me where packages are installed, if I can use them in my scripts.
But actually, pip installs packages in .../APPData/... but search for them in my .venv directory if I try to list / use them !
How can I resolve this behavior please ?
(I would prefer use the .venv directory for downloaded packages through pip, but if you have a solution for using the packages in /AppData/ when I execute my .py scripts, it would be an acceptable workaround)

Finally found my problem.
I had an environment variable "PIP_TARGET" that was set on my system.
a "set PIP_TARGET= " solved this problem

Post this as an answer below and accept it.

I found my problem.
I had an environment variable PIP_TARGET set on my system.
Removing its value via set PIP_TARGET=
solved this problem.

on Linux unset is the cleanest solution. Try: unset PIP_TARGET.
Here more options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222724/command-line-to-remove-an-environment-variable-from-the-os-level-configuration
